Why different signs: Nachash vs Tannin?
I would like to understand why in Sefer Shemot YHWH gives Moses the sign of turning his rod into a nachash for the elders of Israel, and later when both Moses and Aaron are in front of Pharoah, Aaron's rod is turned into a tannin? I guess my question is why is the nachash for Israel and the tannin for Egypt?

Great question! Your question is answered by both Ramban and Chizkuni on the relevant verses; I’ve quoted them below for reference:
Exodus 4:3

וַיֹּ֙אמֶר֙ הַשְׁלִיכֵ֣הוּ אַ֔רְצָה וַיַּשְׁלִכֵ֥הוּ אַ֖רְצָה וַיְהִ֣י
לְנָחָ֑שׁ וַיָּ֥נׇס מֹשֶׁ֖ה מִפָּנָֽיו׃
[God] said, “Cast it on the ground.” He cast it on the ground and it
became a snake; and Moses recoiled from it.

Ramban on this verse says

AND HE SAID: CAST IT ON THE GROUND. AND HE CAST IT ON THE GROUND. I do
not understand why G-d performed the signs before Moses. Moses
believed that it is the Holy One, blessed be He, Who speaks with him,
and it would have been fitting for Him to say, “The staff that is in
your hand you shall cast on the ground before them, and it shall
become a serpent,” and the same also with respect to the second sign,
[i.e., his hand becoming leprous], just as He said at the third sign,
and thou shalt take of the water of the river, and pour it upon the
dry land, etc. It is for this reason that the words of our Rabbis can
be relied upon, namely, that the first sign, [i.e., the staff turning
into a serpent], was a hint to Moses that he had slandered the
Israelites [when he said that they would not believe him], and the
second sign was for the purpose of punishing him. And this is the
sense of the expression, and Moses fled from before it [the serpent].
He feared lest he would be punished and the serpent would bite him,
since every person naturally avoids danger, even though Moses knew
that if it was indeed G-d’s desire [to punish him], there was no one
that could deliver him out of His hand. Perhaps even though He
informed Moses of the Great Name with which the world was created and
everything came into existence, He wished to show him that with this
Name signs and wonders would be done, changing the natural order of
things, so that the matter would be firmly established in Moses’ heart
and that he should in truth know that with the Great Name he will
perform new things in the world. The first two signs were sufficient
for Moses, and therefore the third miracle of the water [turning into
blood] was not done here. Instead, G-d commanded him to do the third
sign in the sight of the people.

And then Exodus 7:9

כִּי֩ יְדַבֵּ֨ר אֲלֵכֶ֤ם פַּרְעֹה֙ לֵאמֹ֔ר תְּנ֥וּ לָכֶ֖ם מוֹפֵ֑ת
וְאָמַרְתָּ֣ אֶֽל־אַהֲרֹ֗ן קַ֧ח אֶֽת־מַטְּךָ֛ וְהַשְׁלֵ֥ךְ
לִפְנֵֽי־פַרְעֹ֖ה יְהִ֥י לְתַנִּֽין׃
“When Pharaoh speaks to you and says, ‘Produce your marvel,’ you shall
say to Aaron, ‘Take your rod and cast it down before Pharaoh.’ It
shall turn into a serpent.”

On this Chizkuni says

והשלך לפני פרעה יהי לתניו, “throw it in front of Pharaoh so that it
will turn into a sea monster.” The reason for this was that Pharaoh
boasted of his power to the extent that G-d in Ezekiel 29,3 called him
“the great sea monster.” The prophet there ridicules the actual power
of Pharaoh who people were afraid of. Moses’ performing the miracle,
was to show him that awe-inspiring monsters are only an illusion and
can be turned into a stick by merely taking hold of their tail.
Similarly, Pharaoh’s power is also only an illusion. Even though it
appears that at this time he is all-powerful, this can change in the
time it takes to drop a stick to the ground.


The Chibbah Yeteira answers that in the wilderness (where Hashem spoke to Moshe) it turned to a snake because the wilderness is a “place of snakes”, whereas in Egypt it turned to a Tanin because Egypt is a “place of Taninim”
Rabbeinu Bachya says that a Nachash and Tanin are the same thing, and the proof is precisely that both words are used

I thought I'd answered this before here but can't find it; here goes. A teacher of mine explained that nachash refers to slander and other antisocial behavior (going all the way back to Eden); Moses had slandered the people by claiming they were nonbelievers, so he was shown a nachash.
Tanin is used in the sense of the majesty of G-d's creation (including at the beginning of Genesis); the Pharaoh didn't believe in that, so he was shown a tanin.
